# Meaning of Continuous Charge in the Inductively Shunted Cooper Pair Box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, superconductivity, quantum-computer

I asked this question on QC.stackexchange before, but received no answers and only the advise to post ist here. Thus:

In the Cooper Pair box, the conjugate momentum $\hat{n}$ of the reduced superconducting phase variable $\hat{\varphi}$ takes only discrete, integer values due to the $2\pi$ periodicity of the phase. As this conjugate momentum is the relative charge number on the island, this corresponds to the discrete charge on the island.

[image]

In the inductively shunted CPB, the inductance destroys the periodicity of the potential in $\varphi$, we have a $\frac{1}{2}E_L \varphi^2$ term additional to the usual $\cos{(\varphi)}$ term of the Josephson Junction.

Now Girvin (http://www.capri-school.eu/lectureres/master_cqed_les_houches.pdf, after 4.41) or Koch et al. (PRL **103**, 217004 (2009)) write that this leads to the charge variable becoming continuous as opposed to integer-valued like in the CPB.

Formally, this makes sense to me: As we do not have periodic boundary conditions for $\varphi$ anymore, we will not have discreteness of the conjugate momentum, i.e. the charge anymore.

**I wonder, however, how to interpret this physically:** After all, the transferred charge must still be quantized in the form of Cooper pairs. So what is meant by the continuity of the charge here? Is it somehow related to the Cooper pair being "part through" the inductance, which isn't lumped but distributed in a real circuit?